# Creating Python dictionaries with keys based on items in list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm creating a dictionary where if the key has an `'R'` then one list, otherwise it goes in the list for `'E'`. My code so far:

```
d1 = {'SSW 540': ['E', 'SYEN'], 'SSW 564': ['R', 'SFEN'], 'SSW 567': ['R', 'SFEN'], 'CS 501': ['E', 'SFEN']}

rlist = []
elist = []

for k, v in d1.items():
    if v[0] == 'R':
        rlist.append([v[1], k])
    elif v[0] == 'E':
        elist.append([v[1], k])
```

Output is:

```
rlist = [['SFEN', 'SSW 564'], ['SFEN', 'SSW 567']]
elist = [['SYEN', 'SSW 540'], ['SFEN', 'CS 501']]
```

How could I create two dictionaries, call them `rdict` and `edict` where:

```
rdict = {'SFEN': ['SSW 564','SSW 567']}
edict = {'SYEN': ['SSW 540'], 'SFEN': ['CS 501']}
```

There could be more values than just `'SYEN'` and `'SFEN'` so it needs to be any particular first element in the list.

If I try something like:

```
mlist = {}

for list in rlist:
    if list[0] in rlist:
        mlist.append(list[1])
    else:
        mlist[list[0]].append(list[1])
```

I get `KeyError: 'SFEN'`. Could I use defaultdict for this?

Comment: You can use `dict.setdefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to create `m_dict` from `d1` directly.

```py
d1 = {
    'SSW 540': ['E', 'SYEN'],
    'SSW 564': ['R', 'SFEN'],
    'SSW 567': ['R', 'SFEN'],
    'CS 501': ['E', 'SFEN'],
}

m_dict = {}
for value, (category, key) in d1.items():
    m_dict.setdefault(category, {}).setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(m_dict)
```

output:

```
{'E': {'SYEN': ['SSW 540'], 'SFEN': ['CS 501']}, 'R': {'SFEN': ['SSW 564', 'SSW 567']}}
```

Explanation:

- `dict.setdefault(key, default)`

  - It sets at `key` by `default` if `key` doesn't exist.
  - And return always value of `key` itself.
- `for value, (category, key) in d1.items():`

  - You can  unpack fixed-length tuple, list, or other sequences.
  - So it is equivalent with:

```py
for value, tuple_ in d1.items():
    category, key = tuple_
```

Comment: This answer is beautiful!